# React Route not adding forward slash with path="/post/:slug"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, sanity

For some reason when I click on one of the posts in the collection of posts section to view the info on one single post, my code is not adding a forward slash `/` in the URL like so : `http://localhost:3000/postyou-just-could-not-have` where the URL I need is `http://localhost:3000/post/you-just-could-not-have`.

Is there a way to add a `/` to the URL or figure out why it is not being generated?

App.js with Route `<Route path="/post/:slug" element={<SinglePost />} />` in question :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import SinglePost from './components/SinglePost';
import Post from './components/Post';
import Project from './components/Project';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/post/:slug" element={<SinglePost />} />
        <Route path="/post" element={<Post />} />
        <Route path="/project" element={<Project />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}


export default App;
```

SinglePost.js component attempting to build URL from slug value :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import sanityClient from '../client';
import BlockContent from '@sanity/block-content-to-react';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(sanityClient);
function urlFor(source) {
  return builder.image(source);
}


export default function SinglePage() {
  const [singlePost, setSinglePost] = useState(null);
  const { slug } = useParams();

 
  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient
      .fetch(
        `*[slug.current == "${slug}"]{
      title,
      _id,
      slug,
      mainImage{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      },
      body,
      "name": author->name,
      "authorImage": author->image
    }`
      )
      .then((data) => setSinglePost(data[0]))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, [slug]);

  if (!singlePost) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <main className="bg-gray-200 min-h-screen p-12">
      <article className="container shadow-lg mx-auto bg-green-100 rounded-lg">
        <header className="relative">
          <div className="absolute h-full w-full flex items-center justify-center p-8">
            <div className="bg-white bg-opacity-75 rounded p-12">
              <h1 className="cursive text-3xl lg:text-6xl mb-4">
                {singlePost.title}
              </h1>
              <div className="flex justify-center text-gray-800">
                <img
                  src={urlFor(singlePost.authorImage).url()}
                  alt="bob"
                  className="w-10 h-10 rouded-full"
                />
                <p className="cursive flex items-center pl-2 text-2xl">
                  {singlePost.name}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <img
            src={singlePost.mainImage.asset.url}
            alt="gary"
            className="w-full object-cover rounded-t"
            style={{ height: '400px' }}
          />
        </header>
        <div className="px-16 lg:px-48 py-12 lg:py-20 prose lg:prose-xl max-w-full">
          <BlockContent
            blocks={singlePost.body}
            projectId="notReally"
            dataset="production"
          />
        </div>
      </article>
    </main>
  );
}



Adding Post.js :
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import sanityClient from '../client';

export default function Post() {
  const [postData, setPost] = useState(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient
      .fetch(
        `*[_type == "post"]{
      title,
      slug,
      mainImage{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        },
        alt
      }
    }`
      )
      .then((data) => setPost(data))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  //anything wrapped in Link makes it clickable
  return (
    <main className="bg-green-100 min-h-screen p-12">
      <section className="container mx-auto">
        <h1 className="text-5xl flex justify-center cursive">Blog Post Page</h1>
        <h2 className="text-lg text=gray-600 flex justify-center mb-12">
          Welcome Doggies
        </h2>
        <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-8">
          {postData &&
            postData.map((post, index) => (
              <article>
                <Link to={'/post' + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current}>
                  <span
                    className="block h-64 relative rounded shadow leading-snug bg-white border-l-8 border-green-400"
                    key={index}
                  >
                    <img
                      src={post.mainImage.asset.url}
                      alt="photo"
                      className="w-full h-full rounded-r object-cover absolute"
                    />
                    <span className="block relative h-full flex justify-end items-end pr-4 pb-4">
                      <h3 className="text-gray-800 text-lg font-blog px-3 py-4 bg-red-700 text-red-100 bg-opacity-75 rounded">
                        {post.title}
                      </h3>
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </Link>
              </article>
            ))}
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't see the code that generates that url

Comment: Any chance showing us `<Post />` or at least how the navigation to `<SinglePost />` is implemented?

Comment: @JohnLi Thanks.  Added Post.js to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are relative to the route hierarchy by default, unless given a value begin with `/`.

[More about `Link`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link)

In `<Post />`, try one of the following:

```
<Link to={post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current}>
...
/Link>
```

Or:

```
<Link to={'/post/' + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current}>
...
/Link>
```

These will hopefully generate the right path as `/post/:slug`.

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks and found my typo not adding the trailing /.